# Why is jumbotron not covering the height of the divs?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am learning bootstrap and I am making a test page where I have two divs inside a jumbotron.

Normally, the jumbotron has a gray background that covers all the content inside of it, but when I add this two divs the jumbotron changes height to  about 50px tall and doesn't cover the height of the other two divs that I added.

Can anyone explain me how to fix this?

---

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <ul class="rectangle-list">
                <li><a href="">List1 </a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Element </a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="">Element</a> </li>
                                <li><a href="">Element</a> </li>
                                <li><a href="">Element</a> </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="">Element</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="">Element</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Element</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">

            <img src="images/image.jpeg" class="img-responsive"/>
            <img src="images/image.jpeg" class="img-responsive"/>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning "><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> Button</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: With one column]

[image: With two columns]

On the second image you can see how the gray container becomes small.

Comment: You are closing tags incorrectly. Check your ul and li closing tags

Comment: I changed them but still the same.

Comment: The code you posted is ok, as you can see in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u7cxf8tc/). The problem is probably in your custom css.

Comment: @Choma if you make the result screen on the fiddle wider the same happens, my page also when it's small size has the jumbotron correctly, but in medium and large screens this happens.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out!

On bootstrap the col- divs should be nested inside a `<div class='row'>`

Final code:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <ul class="rectangle-list">
                <li><a href="">List1 </a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Element </a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="">Element</a> </li>
                                <li><a href="">Element</a> </li>
                                <li><a href="">Element</a> </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="">Element</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="">Element</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Element</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">

            <img src="images/image.jpeg" class="img-responsive"/>
            <img src="images/image.jpeg" class="img-responsive"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning "><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> Button</a>
    </div>
</div>
```